# Copy files as another user to specific dir in script

Tags: shell, unix, aix, su

Witch user X, I am running a script that generates files into a temporary DIR A.

At the end of my script, i need to copy all those generated files into DIR B but whith a specific user userY in order to have the corret owner/group required in that new DIR.

So i have :

**/home/X/test.txt  with rights userX/groupX**

and i need to have this :

**/var/out/test.txt with rights userY/groupY**

The script is not executed as root so i cannot just copy the file as user A and do a **chown**

My idea was to add this in my script :

```
for file in "$OUTPUT_DIR"/*.txt
do
sudo su - userY<<'EOF'
cp $file /var/out/
EOF
done
```

I modified sudoers file so it doesn't prompt me for a password when executing su.

The problem with that approach is that my `cp` commands are not working because the variable `$file` is not preserved when doing `su` to userY.

I've read a lot of other posts saying i could user `sudo -E` or `su -m` to preserve environnement variables but this requires specific privileges and doesn't seem to work also.

I also tried this solution :

```
su userY -c "cp $file $dest"
```

But since my command has variables, even if i add `su userY -c` to sudoers file it keeps asking me for password because my command contains variables and is never the same..

I feel that there is a much easier solution to my problem...

Comment: Can you not just do it with `setgid` on the directory and a umask? Alternatively - write a script that 'does it', and configure 'sudo' to allow you to run that script.

Comment: It's a shell script i do not have access to setgid command (it's from C library right ?). I need all of that to be done in the same script

Comment: How about `sudo -u userY cp $file $dest` ?

Comment: Set it on the directory, all files created in the directory will be set to that group id.

Comment: @Mika : i do not have permissions to do this

Comment: @Sobrique : i am on AIX system i do not have access to setgid

Comment: `chgrp somegroup dirname`. `chmod g+s dirname`. Will make all newly created files in that directory owned by that group. Then either set umask or `chmod g+w` on any files.

Comment: I need to make the files owned by that group but also by that userY